# artifactory not started after machine reboot

Tags: service, debian, artifactory, vsphere

I have installed artifactory 3.0.3 on a debian 7 virtual machine. When I reboot the virtual machine using vSphere artifactory is not restarted. I originally started artifactory as root with

```
service artifactory start
```

which worked fine. There is also an artifactory script here:

```
/etc/init.d/artifactory
```

why is that script not picked up on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that `/etc/init.d/artifactory` service was added to the default runlevels?
You should see symbolic links to the service in the `/etc/rcX.d/` directories (where X is the runlevel number).
To add the service to the [default runlevels](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/) use `update-rc.d`:

```
update-rc.d artifactory defaults
```